# points as function parameters C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

this is probably a simple solution I am not that familiar with C just trying to port my java data structure assignments to C.

this is the error i am getting:

test.c:4: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

test.c:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void to_screen(NODE *cur){
    while(cur->next != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

void add_first(NODE *head, int data){
    NODE *cur;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        cur = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        cur->data = data;
        cur->next = (*head).next;

        head->next = cur;
    }
}

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct element *next;
}NODE;


int main(){
    int i;
    NODE *head;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        add_first(head, i);
    }

    to_screen(head);
}
```

Comment: Aside from moving the typedef to the top, shouldn't it read: `typedef struct node{ int data; struct node *next; }NODE;`?

Comment: yes, thats solved the last part of my problem, thanks

Comment: There is another problem in this code. `NODE * head` in main function may point to anywhere, and it is also a parameter of `add_first()`. Since `add_first()` reads head by `head->next`, it will cause segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the definition of your struct above the to_screen function. The compiler is saying that it doesn't know what NODE is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define NODE before it is used. Move the definition to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this block to the top as 2 other answers recommend.

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct element *next;
}NODE;
```

You may ask for the reason. The reason is that C language specification is not like Java. So it kinds of compiling from the top to the bottom. So, if it see something undefined, it will look for definition above that point, and if it sees the definition it gets it. It doesn't look below the line of code

Comment: It's not about the compiler being smart or dumb. It's about being single-pass or multi-pass.

Comment: It's about the *language specification* not the compiler.

Comment: Ops, ok. I don't know about that. I always blame the compiler